# Should I do anything if I catch my cat sleeping on the floor?

Tags: cats, behavior, sleep

I have two cats from one litter. One of them is visibly larger, more approachable and likes to lie down on the floor the second she gets the chance. Although she doesn't do that all the time.
When her surroundings become peaceful - that is when nobody is walking back and forth etc - she lays her head on the ground and slowly falls asleep. I catch her do this about 3-4 times in a week if not more.

Sometimes, she'd sleep on my bed and then she would go on the floor to sleep again. I found it adorable in a way but at the same time I'd almost always pick her up and put her on any of her favorite sleeping posts (other than floor of course) that is way softer and warmer.

My question is, should I do anything about this repetitive behaviour? I have only been picking her up due to the feeling that the floor isn't something good to nap/sleep on.

Comment: If the cat is comfortable sleeping on the floor, then unless you are worried about stepping on her I'd say leave her there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My cat does this too. You have to remember, cats were not always domestic animals. They still have instincts and memories from when they were wild animals. In the wild, there is no fluffy bed or cat post, and if there was it was probably a furry predator. Naturally, being small animals, they would sleep wherever they felt safe. Whether that be a pile of dirt or a tree. I'm not saying your cat doesn't feel safe on your bed, but maybe he feels like he is more hidden somewhere else. Or just lays there because it has your scent on it. Often, my cat prefers a cardboard box over my bed. I put some papers in the bottom and viola, perfect cat bed. There is nothing wrong with your cat sleeping on the floor. It won't harm him in any way shape or form. It is very annoying when you spend lots of money on a fancy toy and then your cat likes the packaging instead.

Answer (score 4):

If the temperature in your house gets above 23-25C it is normal for most cats to lay on a hard surface to cool themselves down.

Absolutely all cats in the world do this, both the big cats in nature and the small ones we have in our homes.

For small house cats living both inside and outside our houses, it is normal to hide in the shade in bushes if the day is too hot with their belly flat on the soil to keep cool.

Answer (score 2):

The cat is fine. Although I'm not an expert, I have had multiple cats since I was a small child. All but one one of my cats did this same exact behavior, more of less. If you think that you might step on your pet, then go ahead and  move her, but if she's comfortable and not acting out of the ordinary, she's fine. If she's happy, that's what counts.

Answer (score 1):

Cats can't change their clothes (at least not as quickly as we can) nor adjust the thermostat, so when they are too hot or too cold, they will find *places* to nap that will help fix the problem.

In the winter, mine position themselves under heating vents, and in the summer, they will nap on windowsills or beg to go outside and sun themselves on the warm brick patio. OTOH, after they get worked up playing, they will lie on the cold tile or wood floors until they cool back down.

As long as the floor locations she's picking don't put her in danger of being stepped on or tripped over, it's probably best to leave her be.

Answer (score -2):

Well my cat does this all the time but she just started doing it, but then I realized she always lied down on the floor next to her food in that case she is probably hungry